# How to implement secure remember username and password in react.js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

```
<Formik
    initialValues={LoginSchema}
    validationSchema={LoginSchemaValidation}
    onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
      this.handleSubmit(values);
      setSubmitting(false);
      resetForm();
    }}
  >
    <Form>
      <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <Field name="username" type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <div className="input-group-text">
            <span>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} />
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p className="errors">
        <ErrorMessage name="username" />
      </p>
      <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <Field
          name="password"
          type="password"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Password"
        />

        <div className="input-group-append">
          <div className="input-group-text">
            <span>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLock} />
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p className="errors">
        <ErrorMessage name="password" />
      </p>

      <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <label>
          <Field name="isRemember" type="checkbox"/> Remember Me
        </label>
      </div>

      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-yellow btn-block">
            Sign In
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Form>
  </Formik>
```

This is my react form for user input, i used spring boot as backend.
Now i want to implement remember me feature at front-end
Is it secure to store username and password in local storage?
If not then how should i implement this functionality?

Comment: Store username and password is not safe. Usually, you should store something like the access token. In frontend you should check if there's this info in local storage and redirect the user where you want. Otherwise you can use cookies, but it's on springboot side

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335183/i-want-to-implement-remember-username-and-password-in-spring-boot-app-react
Please see this question

Comment: I post the question how to do it in spring boot but did not get answer yet

Comment: i have the same problem, so if you found a way for this i'll be thanksful to check your way